# How can I get a fun little creature to run on top of my active windows?

Tags: window-manager

How can I get a fun little creature to run on top of my active windows?

Just for a fun bit of Linux based eye candy.

Comment: I really can't believe people jumping on closing this Q&A. My verdict is to leave it open.

Comment: @Videonauth I kind of get the unclear what you are asking vote, it was very hard to work the quest6ion for something so strange but too broad? I don't think it could be any more specific.

Comment: I left my comment because I had this question in the close vote cue. and i not voted to close it, I opted for leaving it open. I feel it simply wrong why someone jumps there and close votes on that. I left my message for those coming after me to decide on this so they see. Neither is real an issue here, since you did a Q&A, so not to broad, and not unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found this recently and thought I would share this little bit of eye candy.

Download AMOR

```
wget launchpadlibrarian.net/221203542/amor_15.08.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i amor_15.08.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Start it from dash and then right click the creature to edit some settings

[image]

Here is Tux

[image]

Here is Nico the cat

[image]

Just a bit of fun :) The creatures are fully animated and run around and interact with your windows.